# How can I target post notices with custom CSS?

Tags: support, design

I use Stylish to increase various font sizes on SE.  (This seems to work better than zooming the site, which sometimes breaks other layout.)  I can't figure out how to target a post notice for styling (there doesn't seem to be a relevant class).

For example, [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/24640/325) has two annotations, a post notice and a protection notice.  The HTML source for the former is:

```
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <div class='question-status'>
                <p>We&#39;re looking for long answers that provide some explanation
                   and context. Don&#39;t just give a one-line answer; explain why your 
                   answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don&#39;t include
                   explanations may be removed.
                </p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

and for the latter is:

```
    <div class="question-status">
        <h2>
            <b>protected</b> by <a href="/users/7945/jmac">jmac</a>
            <span class="mod-flair" title="moderator">♦</span> 
            <span title="2014-05-30 00:53:39Z" class="relativetime">14 hours ago</span>
        </h2>
        <p>
            This question is protected to prevent &quot;thanks!&quot;, &quot;me too!&quot;, 
            or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 
            <a href="/help/whats-reputation">reputation</a> on this site.
        </p>
    </div>
```

Overriding font-size on `question-status` doesn't do the trick.  I'm trying to target the actual text of the notices.  How do I do that?

(I'm a CSS novice, but so far finding "class=foo" in promising places and attaching styling seems to be working out.)

Comment: If somebody knows how to fix the formatting to show the actual HTML in those code blocks, I'd really appreciate a fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text on the post notices appear to be wrapped in a paragraph tag, a `<p>`, which in turn is wrapped inside a `div.question-status`.  With this knowledge, we can build a CSS selector specific enough to target paragraph tags that also happen to be enclosed in these divs:

In the spirit of the [Many Memes of Meta for jQuery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/155826), here's some jQuery that targets these post notices, both on questions as well as answers, and increases the font size:

```
$('.question-status p').css('font-size','15px');
```

In the spirit of using real, actual CSS, you could also target these notices like so:

```
.question-status p {
    font-size: 15px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  With the addition of `!important` that CSS did the trick for me.  (And now I know how to specify nested elements in CSS, yay.)